# Update variable in fileA from fileB

Tags: python

**fileA.py**

```
variable_a = {
    "hello" : "world"
}

variable_b = {
    "foo" : "bar
}
```

Is there a way to load fileA.variable_b, update "foo" value from the file ?
I file like Pickle module could hlp me doing that but I am not managing to load fileA

**fileB.py**

```
import pickle

with open('fileA.py', 'rb') as file:
  a = pickle.load(file)
```

when i print `a` it gives me an error

```
File "fileB.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = pickle.load(file)
KeyError: 101
```

Thank you for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

The best way to import variable from another python file in the same directory is to use it as a library
With your example it would be

```
from fileA import variable_a

# Now use variable_a, for example 
print(variable_a)
```

Use `with open` for a txt or a json file

Comment: my point is that i need to update the variable_b and not just import and read the value. I need to update it from another file